# Missing ouptut in exe file

Tags: debugging, visual-c++

I am using following C++ code to enter a value of X which is used to print out variable CDF. This C++ code is expected to give very similar value we get from NORMDIST function in excel. However I get following error in debugger with out getting any output in executable file. Can any body help please?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;
const double pi = 4.0*atan(1.0);
int main()
{
  const double a1 = 0.319381530, a2 = -0.356563782, a3 = 1.781477937, 
  a4 = -1.821255978, a5 = 1.330274429;
  double X = 0, x = 0; double k = 0;
  double N, CDF, n;
  cout << "Enter the value of the random variable X" << endl;
  cin >> X;
  x = fabs(X);
  k = 1 / (1 + 0.2316419*x);
  n = (1 / sqrt(2 * pi))*exp(-0.5*x*x);
  N = 1 - n*(a1*k + a2*k*k + a3*pow(k, 3) + a4*pow(k, 4) + a5*pow(k, 5));
  CDF = N;
  if (X < 0)
    CDF = 1 - N;
 cin.clear();
 cout << CDF;
 cin.get();
  return 0;
}
```

I CDF1.exe for output for example for X= 0.7693 as input, I am expecting 0.7791 but I don't see any output in CDF1.exe and I just see below in debugger. Can anybody help in trouble shoot please?

```
'CDF1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\kdatta\Documents\CQF\C++\CDF1 Debug\CDF1.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'CDF1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'CDF1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'CDF1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'CDF1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp120d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'CDF1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr120d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
The thread 0x4fc0 has exited with code -1073741749 (0xc000004b).
The program '[11216] CDF1.exe' has exited with code -1073741510 (0xc000013a).
```

Comment: When googling the exit code, I found this: Exit code returned when the process exited when the Control+C key was pressed.Value: 0xC000013A - sound reasonable? Have you tried single-stepping through the code?

Comment: nope. Programm prompts to enter value of X. Once I enter the value of X, it seems its exiting. Not sure why?

Comment: Like I said... try single stepping through the code. Then you will know how far it is getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that in debug mode the code returns immediately and you don't see the result. You have to force the program to pause when you are in debug mode. You can put `system("pause")`

```
#include<iostream>
int main()
{
  std::cout << "hello world\n";

#ifdef _DEBUG
  system("pause");
#endif

  return 0;
}
```

PDB files contain debug information. Those are warnings not errors. Try to get rid of them by rebuilding the project.

Also, click Project -> Properties, make sure you have these settings:

`C/C++ -> General -> Program Database for Edit And Continue (/ZI)`

`Linker -> Debugging -> Generate Debugging Info = Yes`